# Launch my kernel in grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

So I've followed a simple tutorial (http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernel-101-lets-write-a-kernel) and i have the kernel file successfully created and put in the boot folder. I have added the following under the part about making my own kernel:

```
menuentry '[HIDDEN ON SO]' --class [HIDDEN ON SO] --class [HIDDEN ON SO] {
    kernel /boot/kernel-899 ro
}
```

but when i launch my kernel from the grub menu it says "kernel: no such command"
please help - there doesnt seem to be an existing answer for something like this

Comment: I see `menuentry 'kernel 7001' {
 set root='hd0,msdos1'
 multiboot /boot/kernel-7001 ro
}` not what you have here. Make sure you followed the steps properly.

Comment: @George after doing that it says "no disk found: 'hd0,msdos1' "

Comment: I hope your doing this in a __VM__. I suggest you go through the steps again to make sure you got it right.

Comment: @George im not doing it in a virtual machine (and i never will) and i have just gone and checked through it all again and it seems good. but it cant find the disk for it. I have got the compiled kernel file in the /boot directory. named kernel-899. so what am i actually meant to set the root to